# Save .mp4 to Windows Phone video library

Tags: c#, download, windows-phone-8.1, mp4, win-universal-app

I was wondering how I can download an MP4 video file from a URI and save it to the media library on Windows Phone 8.1. 
It would be great if it worked in a Universal App - but it doesn't have to.

I found this code to save an image to the camera roll - do I go the same way about this with an *.mp4 to save it to the video library? And can I just hand off a download stream (not sure if that makes sense) to that function?

```
StorageFolder testFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\test");
StorageFile sourceFile = await testFolder.GetFileAsync("TestImage.jpg");
StorageFile destinationFile = await KnownFolders.CameraRoll.CreateFileAsync("MyTestImage.jpg");

using (var sourceStream = await sourceFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
    using (var sourceInputStream = sourceStream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
    {
        using (var destinationStream = await destinationFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (var destinationOutputStream = destinationStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
            {
                await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(sourceInputStream, destinationStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, this is what my code looks like:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var file = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    StorageFile destinationFile 
        = await KnownFolders.SavedPictures.CreateFileAsync("file.mp4",
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream stream = await destinationFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    IOutputStream output = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);

    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(output);
    writer.WriteBytes(file);
    await writer.StoreAsync();
    await output.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: You should enable **ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO** Capability in **WMAppManifest.xml** to access "**SavedPictures**" Album.

Comment: hi , I tried this for windows phone 8.1 but not able to download video. can you please help me out.. I have video url to download that..